# Angular Generator Fails - missing package.json

Tags: genexus

I'm using the latest u10 release of version 17. I can generate an Angular front end 1 time on any project. After that, I get the following error:

```
    Command: cmd /c npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Models\Learn2\CSQLServer\mobile\Angular/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Models\Learn2\CSQLServer\mobile\Angular\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Crowley\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-11T13_10_17_493Z-debug-0.log
Failed: Angular Execution
Failed: Run Developer Menu
```

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing all Genexus files. I've also tried creating different environments, but still the same result.

The logs point to a missing package.json file - it appears Genexus isn't generating it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Genexus got back to me and resolved. I did not have HTTP Activation enabled in IIS apparently.   https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22037,Image%3AWCF+enable+http+activation

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information on the solution of this thread.

The first error (*) was solved by defining the Panel as startup object.
So, the mobile folder was created with the package.json file.

(*)  npm ERR! path C:\Models\Learn2\CSQLServer\mobile\Angular/package.json

The second error (**) was related to not having activated the feature [WCF HTTP Activation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22037,Image%3AWCF%20enable%20http%20activation) on IIS that is needed to invoke REST services

(**) HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found